# Shared attribute with react-navigation-fluid-transitions not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, transition

I making a app in React native and found a cool [transition library](https://github.com/fram-x/FluidTransitions).
Everything works fine exept the `shared="name"` attribute. The shared attribute is supposed to make a smooth transition of elements between navigations ex move and flip element. Navigation works fine.

Screen1

```
<Transition appear="left" shared='paper'>
 <View style={styles.paper1} />
</Transition>
```

Screen2

```
<Transition shared='paper'>
 <View style={styles.paper2} />
</Transition>
```

If i have `shared` to same names I get this error that dont help a lot, and if i dont have same name obviously the transition is not working as expected:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\AnimatedEvent.js:94:46 in AnimatedEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Animated\src\AnimatedImplementation.js:504:42 in event
- ... 37 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Has anyone used this library and got `shared` to work? Looked at the doc and found a [working example](https://snack.expo.io/@chrfalch/shoe-shop) but cant figure out what is wrong with my code.

Here is a pastebin of all [MY CODE](https://pastebin.com/m4PzGt2z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just messed up somewhere. Here is your working example https://snack.expo.io/Hyk806!HI